# xml to csv using xslt - download the result

Tags: xml, xslt, csv

I've got an XML file in the following format

```
<result_set>
    <results>
        <review>
            <byline>name</byline>
            <display_title>title</display_title>
            <mpaa_rating>R</mpaa_rating>
            <publication_date>2014-1-1</publication_date>
            <headline>text</headline>
            <summary_short>summary</summary_short>
       </review>
   </results>
</result_set>
```

and the xsl as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <HTML>
    <BODY>  
        <xsl:for-each select="result_set/results/review">
            <div>
                <xsl:value-of select="byline"/>,<xsl:value-of select="display_title"/>,<xsl:value-of select="mpaa_rating"/>,<xsl:value-of select="publication_date"/>,<xsl:value-of select="headline"/>,<xsl:value-of select="summary_short"/>
            </div>
        </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </BODY>
    </HTML>
  </xsl:template>
```

The information displays on the html page just fine, I was wondering if there was any better way of writing the xsl. As well as that, I want the user to be able to download csv into a file. How can i do this?

Comment: It seems OK (if you also have an `<xsl:template match="/*"/>` to get rid of the text nodes). Are you generating this in a browser? If you are generating it on the server side you can redirect the output to a file and link it.

Comment: @helderdarocha the files are on a server. how do i redirect the output?

Comment: How are you running the XSLT processor? Are you using a program? Java? PHP? C#? You usually just need to save the result file in a server directory which allows downloads (ex: most document directories - it depends on your server configurations, permissions, etc.)

Comment: @helderdarocha  oh...i misunderstood your question. It's the browser that displays the result. server only holds the file.

Comment: If you generate a pure text file (use '<xsl:output method="text"/>') the user can perhaps save the file as text if he/she wishes.